# Autoconf/configure not finding tools for cross compiling

Tags: linux, compilation, cross-compiling, configure, autoconf

I'm trying to cross-compile libSDL version 1.2 (which leverages autoconf and configure) for a custom made, Debian based Linux system. The toolchain I'm using is already configured properly so that I just run `gcc`/`g++` on the desired code and the resulting output is compatible with the target machine.

When I run `./configure --help` in the libSDL source directory, I see that I can basically just set some environment variables to point to my cross-compiler, and I also see the following options:

```
System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
```

I set these options so that, it seems, configure knows that I'm trying to cross compile as evident by the output line `checking whether we are cross compiling... yes` which says 'yes' when the `--build` and `--host` flags differ. However, I'm not 100% sure that this is what causes it to know I'm cross-compiling.

My problem is that configure picks up my compiler (that I set with an env. var.) and detects gcc, but it can't find other build tools like objdump, for example. It should be looking in /bin/ (where all the other build tools are) but I'm guessing it's not looking in the right spot.

This is my command and output:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/sudoroot/code/sal_wip/libsdl/SDL-1.2.15/prefix_dir --exec-prefix=/home/sudoroot/code/sal_wip/libsdl/SDL-1.2.15/exec-prefix_dir --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux
<...>
checking for i686-linux-gcc... /toolchain/x86_gcc-4.7.2_eglibc-2.17-r22120_i686-host-linux-gnu-2/bin/i686-linux-gcc
checking for i686-linux-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
configure: WARNING: In the future, Autoconf will not detect cross-tools
whose name does not start with the host triplet.  If you think this
configuration is useful to you, please write to autoconf@gnu.org.
<...>
```

It looks to me like it couldn't find my cross-compiler objdump, but it did find the host machine's local copy of objdump.

I looked into all of `configure`'s flags and couldn't find anything on setting the cross-compile search directory. How do I get `configure` find my tools in my `/toolchain/<toolchain>/bin` directory?

Comment: Does `/toolchain/x86_gcc-4.7.2_eglibc-2.17-r22120_i686-host-linux-gnu-2/bin/i686-linux-objdump` exist?  Is it executable?  If you are finding the cross-compiler `i686-linux-gcc` the other cross-compilation tools should be found as well, unless there's some problem with the installation of your toolchain.

Comment: Yep, they're both located in the same directory and they both work, that's why I'm a little confused :-\ it was even more strange to see it not find objdump: `checking for i686-linux-objdump... no` but it did find strip: `checking for i686-linux-strip... strip` ... I guess the question now is what's the easiest way to debug this?

Comment: Look at `config.log`.